# How can I get a xhtml element by it's ID?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get the xhtml element ID in javascript to change an element color when I click a button. I expect the browser to find an element added via an function other than `querySelector` and `getElementById`.

As a alternative to the dom default methods, I wrote this function to find element from the nodes tree. I it didn't worked because I used the wrong NodeFilters.

```
function findById(id) {
    const treewalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT | NodeFilter.SHOW_ATTRIBUTE 
        | NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, { acceptNode: function (node) { 
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        } }, false);
    let node;
    let nodes = [];
    while (node = treewalker.nextNode())
        nodes.push(node);
    return nodes.filter(node => node.id === id);
}
```

Here is a minimum reproductable example of what I am trying to do.

```js
    /* Display the foobar text (cannot be directly written in the html file)  */
    let foobar = document.createElement('p');
    foobar.innerHTML = 'Foo bar';
    foobar.id = 'foobar';
    // foobar.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'foobar');
    document.body.appendChild(foobar);

    function findById(id) {
        const treewalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT | NodeFilter.SHOW_ATTRIBUTE 
            | NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, { acceptNode: function (node) { 
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            } });
        let node;
        let nodes = [];
        while (node = treewalker.nextNode())
            nodes.push(node);
        return nodes.filter(node => node.id === id);
    }

    function displayFoobar() {
        let e = findById('foobar');
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.style.color = 'blue';
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.style.color = 'black';
        }, 2000);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Foo bar app</h1>
<button onclick="displayFoobar();">display foobar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FALSE: `id aren't registered when element are added using document.appendChild`.

Comment: Why does IDs are still registered in CSS but not in javascript?

Comment: IDs are registered in the DOM where they are available to CSS and JS.

Comment: Both `getElementById` and `querySelector` work perfectly fine after an `appendChild`, but if you're using XHTML, you still need to follow the rules of HTML, and you need to make sure to use `document.body.appendChild` for normal content, or `document.head.appendChild` for head content. Appending to "the document" makes very little sense.

Comment: Actually, you'd better show us your code where you're appending child and trying to get it via `getElementById`

Comment: I modified the post to include a minimum reproducatable example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code with `document.getElementById` working:

```js
/* Display the foobar text (cannot be directly written in the html file)  */
    let foobar = document.createElement('p');
    foobar.innerHTML = 'Foo bar';
    foobar.id = 'foobar';
    document.body.appendChild(foobar);

    function displayFoobar() {
        let e = document.getElementById('foobar');
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.style.color = 'blue';
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.style.color = 'black';
        }, 2000);
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Foo bar app</h1>
<button onclick="displayFoobar();">display foobar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**
If you really want to use your own custom function, please note that
 `return nodes.filter(node => node.id === id);`
returns an array.
Thus you need its first element:
`let e = findById('foobar')[0];`

```js
    /* Display the foobar text (cannot be directly written in the html file)  */
    let foobar = document.createElement('p');
    foobar.innerHTML = 'Foo bar';
    foobar.id = 'foobar';
    // foobar.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'foobar');
    document.body.appendChild(foobar);

    function findById(id) {
        const treewalker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT | NodeFilter.SHOW_ATTRIBUTE 
            | NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, { acceptNode: function (node) { 
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            } });
        let node;
        let nodes = [];
        while (node = treewalker.nextNode())
            nodes.push(node);
        return nodes.filter(node => node.id === id);
    }

    function displayFoobar() {
        let e = findById('foobar')[0];
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.style.color = 'blue';
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.style.color = 'black';
        }, 2000);
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Foo bar app</h1>
  <button onclick="displayFoobar();">display foobar</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I invite you to look at my post edit. In the previous edits, I didn't really know what I really wanted to have as a goal.

Comment: @ViniDalvino, it's not really clear to me what you wanted. You said that `getElementById` didn't work, now you see it does.

Comment: @ViniDalvino, catch the update, but I'd not recommend it. Your code would be more complicated with no performance / readability / maintainability improvements over the built-in functions...